# AudioToolbox iPad problem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, audiotoolbox

I am implementing AudioToolbox framework into my ipad app to try to play a sound effect. Here is my code: I declared a SystemSoundID called explode

```
NSURL *explodeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  
                      pathForResource:@"Explosion" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) explodeURL, explode);    
[self performSelector:@selector(playsfx) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

-(void)playsfx {
     AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundID(explode)
}
```

But for some reason the sound never plays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing the address of explode

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)explodeURL, &explode);
```